# What is the function $f$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)=n^3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

$$\begin{align*}
1 &\leadsto 1  \\
1+3 &\leadsto 2^2  \\
1+3+5 &\leadsto 3^2  
\end{align*}$$
In general, if $f(x)=2x+1$, then $f(0)+f(1)+f(2)...f(n)=(n+1)^2$.

Now,
$$\begin{align*}
1 &\leadsto 1  \\
1+7+19+\cdots &\leadsto m^3   \\ 
\end{align*}$$ 
Is there a function that generates these numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take the difference between the next, and the current number. For example $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$. Likewise, $(x+1)^3-x^3=3x^2+3x+1$, which is the expression you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: But if the function, more vaguely, was x^n, then would the sum be (x+1)^n-x^n

Comment: @AAron That would work for any function, it is pretty intuitive that $\sum_{i=0}^n\left(f(i+1)-f(i)\right)=f(n+1)-f(0)$